# Modify the XSLT list view for custom field type on Sp2013 in order to customize the totals rendering (Count, Sum, Average etc) - possible SP2013 bug?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, custom-field-type

Just wondering if there is a way through which I could modify the XSL templates for a list view rendering which includes a custom field type, in order to customize the totals row in the view. Recently, I created such a simple custom field type, inheriting from `SPTextField`, I added it to a list, modified the list view and added it to the *Totals* section, but the *Count* total for this field seems to be rendered together with the rest of the rows in the table. This is the section from the fldtypes_CustomFieldType.xsl file which manages the rendering of this field:

```
  <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@FieldType = 'CustomFieldType']" mode="Text_body">
      <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
      <span style="background-color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold">
          test <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
      </span>
  </xsl:template >
```

This is how the column looks like in the list view display:
[image: XSLT rendering of Count for custom field type inside SP2013 list view]

I'm looking forward for your feedback. Thanks!

**[EDIT]**
I described in a post on my own blog this issue with more details and a slightly different perspective:
http://beamusupscotty.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/sharepoint-2013-custom-field-type-vs-aggregation-vs-xslt-list-view-vs-jslink/
I also believe that there is a possible workaround, but time will tell. Please consider the information there before posting your answers. Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose you've had any luck with changing the list view field header using `mode="header"`? I can't seem to get the goshdarn thing to work in 2013.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I described the only workaround I found on my blog page linked above. If you find another solution, please don't forget to update this question with an answer.